# need way better performance in aspx code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, datatable

I've written an asp.net Website which is used for creating Reports (into an Excel) full of specified Items. I get these Items from a SQL DB via EF. The Query works great and needs for about 2000 Items about 1ms.

```
var itemsToQuery = (from i in context.item
    where ......
    .....
    .....
    orderby .......
    select new
    {
    fields.....
});
```

Now it gets tricky for me. Foreach item i have to query extra Data from the DB (no chance to get these Data with the first query). I'm using only one DB connection to safe time (for the main query and every other query in the method). I think my performance problem starts here. I've 2000 Items and the following loop looks like this:

```
foreach(var item in itemsToQuery)
{
      another query;
      another query;
      another query;
      etc.....
      // at the end it looks like
      datatable.add(item.name, item.number, item.stuff ......);
}
```

So i'm doing for each of these 2000 items another 8 queries. This foreach takes about 5 Minutes to be done (depends on the number of items). Afterwards i need this DataTable to fill my Excel sheet. That works fine and "fast".

Can you give me some expert advice how to make this loop, the queries or the filling of the DataTable more performant?

I thought about a workaround with Multitasking and creating a site where you can see the status of the excel (via ajax calls) and when it's done you can download it. Now i just block the UI of this site and the user has to sit in front of the screen until it's done without any information how long he has to wait. Example of the screen with a gif and js for a running clock:

[image: graphic while blocking ui]

One important thing - i **CAN NOT** create views or stored procedures in the database because i'm not allowed to. I have to perform every query etc. in my code behind.

I know the program is written amateurish but that's why i have to change that urgently.

**[EDIT]**

Here are the sample queries i've talked about! Just for information - i didn't wrote every query. Some of them (like `owner` or `monthlyWorkTime`) is from an external resource.

```
String changeDate = CalcÄnderungsDat(context
                     .ticket_history
                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.history_type_id == 25 && x.ticket_id == item.ticketID).change_time.ToString());




String finishdate = CalcFinishDat((from tih in context.ticket_history
                      where (tih.name == "Reset of unlock time." && tih.ticket_id == item.ticketID)
                      || (tih.state_id == 2 && tih.history_type_id == 1 && tih.ticket_id == item.ticketID)
                      select tih.change_time).Max().ToString());


try
{
  string owner= (from a in context.article
                 where
                 item.ticketID == a.ticket_id &&
                 a.id ==
                 (from art in context.article
                 where art.a_subject.Contains("esitzer")
                 && art.ticket.id == item.ticketID
                 && art.ticket_id == art.ticket.id
                 select new { art.id }).Max(p => p.id)
                 select new { a.a_from }).FirstOrDefault().a_from;
}
catch (Exception)
{
 string owner = (from a in context.article
                 where a.ticket.id == item.ticketID && a.ticket_id == a.ticket.id &&
                 a.id ==
                 (from art in context.article
                 where art.ticket.id == item.ticketID
                 && art.ticket_id == art.ticket.id
                 select new { art.id }).Min(p => p.id)
                 select new { a.a_from }).FirstOrDefault().a_from;
}

decimal? monatszeit = (from ta in context.time_accounting
                      where
                      ta.change_time >= startdat &&
                      ta.change_time <= enddat &&
                      ta.ticket_id == item.ticketID
                      group new { ta } by new
                      {
                         ta.ticket_id,
                         ta.ticket.id,
                         ta.ticket.tn
                      } into g
                      select new
                      {
                           Zeiteinheit = (Decimal?)g.Sum(p => p.ta.time_unit),
                      }).SingleOrDefault().Zeiteinheit;
```

And so on. Overall there are 7 queries and 1 external method for calculation a special Date (this method shouldn't be the problem) for each item from the main query. How can i put them in ONE complete query? Would it increase my performance?

**[EDIT - ANOTHER TRY!]**

What do you say about this Flowchart?
[image]

- client sends request to the server server writes an entry into the
  "job" table in the DB
- after sending the request the client gets job_ID from the DB
  immediately
- with this ID client can do AJAX calls for the progress (status)
- the webservice is checking every second if there is a new job with
  status -1 in the DB
- for each job with status -1 create a new task
- in this Task the ReportMaker.GenerateReport(idAUFTRAG) method will be
  called
- ReportMaker has a Event ReportProgress
- the caller (Task) subscribes to this event and writes every change to
  the database
- DB Accessor -> Task
- Client performs Ajax Calls back

That would increase the Performance definitely!!! Does it sound like too much work for such a small project?

Comment: If the "another query" results are not too huge when done without qualifying them with the current itemToQuery values, you might try caching them and just filter them inside your loop.

Comment: What other queries? Why do you have to do them for each item instead of creating relations and loading everything in a single query, eg with the `Include` clause?

Comment: Besides, *reporting* queries are about sets of data, not individual objects. EF doesn't offer anything over eq Dapper on this. The only viable way is to create queries that load each reporting set of data at once instead of loading items one by one. They require the proper schema and typically need views to hide complex queries.

Comment: it's really hard to describe for me without telling you too many "Internal" details. Give me a try:
the first query is very complex (not as easy as i wrote above - about 25 rows of code and thats the short version - no lambda expressions). in this query i get the main datas (where tables are in a relationship). Every following query gets single data from non relational tables. I've tried `include` and `cross joins` but it didn't work as i wanted. Additionally `cross joins` are terrible (specially for performance).  How can i get the additional data for every item without performing a loop?

Comment: the other queries are not that complex but still to big and complex to put them in the main query. with these queries i get only one special value (like a special name, calculated time, etc.) from the database.

Comment: Given that `every following query` gets `single data from non relational tables`, doesn't that imply there IS indeed a relation?

Comment: not directly - i don't want to say that there's a relationship. The other tables don't have a foreign key for this field - they just have a common field without any relations. Please don't ask me why - i haven't designed this DB and i have no influence to change it.

Comment: Yea that is what I meant, they are related, it is just not written into database constraints. If they can be related by a common field it should be quite possible to get everything you want in one query. But here is another approach: You said you cannot create views or procedures, but how about indices? Take a look at the execution plans for your "main" queries and the "dependent" ones, look for wasteful parts such as `Index Scan` or the like and try to replace them by proper index usage with `Index Seeks`, that could speed it up without having to change the code.

Comment: OK - let me explain! The Database is created by a third party product (OTRS). The Database is somewhere on a external server and i'm absolutely NOT allowed to make any changes. I am NOT allowed to change,  delete or modify existing tables/indices/views/procedures/trigger etc. I told you - it's hard to explain. I'm just not allowed to "touch" the Database - just with this asp website.

Comment: The problem with putting every query into one is that the other queries are little bit to complex and little bit too big. Maybe i should show a few examples. I'll change the queries and put them here at the end of my question ok?

Comment: If you're too constrained, you can always split processing into separate ajax requests, so the user keeps getting updates and it feels responsive. I'm afraid there's no magical solution to your constrained problem. Best approach would be the one explained by DrCopyPaste, but if that's not an option...

Comment: I strongly suggest that you fix that query in the try/catch block. Most likely, the exception you are catching is a `NullReferenceException` from `.FirstOrDefault().a_from`. If `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`, then the exception will be thrown. Replace the try/catch with an `if` statement checking for `null`.

Comment: @walther - no don't say that! So my only chance is to change the hole design to be more responsive for the customer.....i'm not that good with ajax but now i think i've a reason to learn everything about it.
Thank you walther!

Comment: @JohnSaunders - stupid question, wouldn't it be the same? in both samples i have to execute the second query when the first one returns null.

Comment: A very big thank you to all who have made so many thoughts about my problem.

Comment: Exception handling is much more expensive than simply testing for `null`.

Comment: right - because of the exception stack and stacktracing etc? I think this will be an easy change for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about creating a cache solution for data already retrieved. So that query results will be stored in memory and it will not be retrieved every time so performance will greatly increase.

You have to think how often to refresh the cache. Other option is to check if some new data appear and make query that will retrieve only newest data.